# complile time error on arraylist.add in android

Tags: android, class, arraylist

> i have one ArrayList; in this i can't able to add the items

below is my code i dnt know what error is i made please help to solve this problem

```
private ArrayList<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

Question is a class with getter and setter

```
public class Question {

private String id;
private String question;
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;
private String option4;

public Question(String id, String question, String option1, String option2,
        String option3, String option4) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.option1 = option1;
    this.option2 = option2;
    this.option3 = option3;
    this.option4 = option4;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
public String getOption1() {
    return option1;
}
public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;
}
public String getOption2() {
    return option2;
}
public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;
}
public String getOption3() {
    return option3;
}
public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;
}
public String getOption4() {
    return option4;
}
public void setOption4(String option4) {
    this.option4 = option4;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return question;
}
```

}

> here i am adding to the array list:

```
JSONArray questions = data.getJSONArray("questions");
                        for(int i =0; i<questions.length();i++)
                        {                               
                            question.add(questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("question"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option1"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option2"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option3"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option4"));
                        }
```

> But i am getting the following compile time error
>
> The method add(int, Question) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String, String)

how to solve this??

Comment: Thank you so much for all the reply its worked me fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new Question in your for loop:

```
JSONArray questions = data.getJSONArray("questions");
for(int i =0; i<questions.length();i++)
{                               
    question.add(new Question(
        questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),
        questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("question"),
        questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option1"),
        questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option2"),
        questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option3"),
        questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option4")
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to add a new question object to the question ArrayList...

```
question.add(new Question("id", "question", "opt1", "opt2", "opt3", "opt4"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the question in the loop, like:

```
  question.add(new Question(questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("question"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option1"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option2"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option3"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option4")) );
```

Answer (score 1):

add instance of Question in arraylist not individual values.

```
question.add(new Question(questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getString("question"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option1"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option2"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option3"),questions.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("options").getString("option4")));
```